# Insects on Field Rose

Tags: roses, bugs, aphids, caterpillar

I'm kinda new to gardening, and also new to my current area.
I'm now living in central London and in my small garden I have a rosebush that I believe is a "Field rose" rosebush. It's not in great shape. There are aphids and tiny caterpillars on it, see pictures attached.

[image]

[image]

Could you please let me know if a) these are really caterpillars and aphids (I'd like to know what I'm up against!) and b) how to get rid of them

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On a small scale you can always pick them off and drop them in soapy water before resorting to poisoning (which can have unintended side effects such as harming insects that would help you by preying on your pests.)

I can't see the possible aphids in your pictures, but there do seem to be small caterpillars in abundance munching on leaves.